# focus problem in mozilla

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my application I am using a text box with onBlur property assigned to a function i cant focus by telling the id in Mozilla the code is as follows

> `<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" autocomplete="off" runat="server" MaxLength="25" Width="350px" TextMode="Password" onBlur="return ValidatePassword(this.text);">
>   </asp:TextBox>`

Javascript function

`function ValidatePassword(element)
  {
     element.focus();
  }`

Comment: I'm confused, when you lose focus on the textbox your javascript causes it to focus it again?  Is that the real content of your javascript function or do you have some validation logic there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onblur` is a client side function, to get the value of the textbox in client side, use `.value` not `.text`.

```
onBlur="return ValidatePassword(this);"

function ValidatePassword(element) {
    if(element.value.length < 5){
        setTimeout(function(){
            element.focus();
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Meister When i give this.value then i wont get the id so i passed it as onBlur="return ValidatePassword(this);" and in the function element.focus now also its not focussing to the control in Mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" 
    autocomplete="off" runat="server" 
    MaxLength="25" Width="350px" TextMode="Password" onBlur="return 
    ValidatePassword(document.getelementById('<%=txtPassword.ClientID%>'));"> 
</asp:TextBox>
```